# CAST statement with expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL select which has this condition:

- If distance supplied in variable is not null then select data less than the mentioned distance
- If distance is null then select rows.

I want to use a `CASE` statement only

Below is my query

```
declare @distance int
set @distance  = 3000

select 
    ROUND((dbo.GetDistance(@UserLat, @UserLon, Latitude, Longitude) * 1000), 0) AS Distance 
from 
    messages     
order by 
    Distance desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, 
          ROUND((dbo.GetDistance(@UserLat, @UserLon, Latitude, Longitude)*1000),0) AS Distance 
   FROM messages ) s
WHERE (@distance IS NULL) OR (s.Distance < @distance)
ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

If `@distance` is null then *all rows* of `messages` will be returned, else only rows having `s.Distance < @distance` are selected.